# How to prove that the solution of $\frac{dy}{dx}=1+y^4$ with $y(x_0)=y_0$ cannot be extended to $\infty$ and $-\infty$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

A friend of mine gave me a proof, but I didn't get it.

If the solution can be extended to +∞

$$ \frac{dy}{1+y^4} = dx $$

Integrate $x$ from $x_0$ to +∞

So $$+∞ = \int_{x_0}^\infty \frac{ dy(x)}{1+y^4 } (\alpha) $$

Let $y$ replace $x$

Then

$$ \alpha = \int_{y_0}^y \frac{dy}{1+y^4} (+∞), $$ which is no greater than from $y_0$ to +∞

So the hypothesis is wrong

The solution cannot be extended to +∞

I don't think $dy$ change into $dy(x)$ is correct during the first integration process. Is this proof right?
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: For me, $a/b+c=\frac{a}{b}+c$... Moreover, you can easily solve such an equation and see what happen !

Comment: Yes, it works along those lines. From the equation you get the equality of differentials $\frac{d(y(x))}{1+y(x)^4}=dx$. Now integrate from $x_0$ to $+\infty$ to get $\int_{x_0}^{+\infty}\frac{d(y(x))}{1+y(x)^4}=\int_{x_0}^{\infty}dx=+\infty$. But the left hand side is equal to $\int_{y_0}^{+\infty}\frac{dy}{1+y^4}$, which is finite.

Comment: There is no problem with changing $\int_{x_0}^{\infty}\frac{d(y(x))}{1+y(x)^4}$ for $\int_{y_0}^{+\infty}\frac{dy}{1+y^4}$. This is just the change of variable formula. Maybe the only difference that you are not used to see is that there is no $y'(x)dx$ in the first one. Instead there is a $d(y(x))$, which is the same.

Comment: If dy(x)/dx>0 on an interval then on the image of that  interval, the inverse function x(y) exists and dx(y)/dy=1/(dy(x)/dx).

Answer (score 1):

Alternative argument: You have at all times $y'\ge 1$. Thus there is a time $x_1$ where $y(x_1)=1$ is reached. From that point on use $y'\ge y^4$ which can be easily solved as
$$
(y^{-3})'=-3y^{-4}y'\le -3\implies y(x)^{-3}-y(x_1)^{-3}\le -3(x-x_1)
\\ ~ \\
\implies y(x)\ge \frac1{\sqrt[3\,]{1-3(x-x_1)}}
$$
so that at some time before $x=x_1+\frac1{3}$ the solution diverges to infinity.